# cocos2d-x JSON file parsing

Tags: c++, json, parsing, cocos2d-x

I have a .json file, containing an array of dictionaries. Can you show me a good way of parsing it? I'm using the cocos2d-x 3.0-alpha version and the json classes, placed in the external/json directory.

I tried:

```
Array* items = Array::createWithContentsOfFile("test.json");
```

and

```
string fullPath = CCFileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename("test.json");
long bufferSize = 0;
const char* mFileData = (const char*)FileUtils::getInstance()->getFileData(fullPath.c_str(), "r", &bufferSize);

string clearData(mFileData);
size_t pos = clearData.rfind("}");
clearData = clearData.substr(0, pos+1);

string data = clearData.c_str();

log("%s", clearData.c_str());

Json::Value _root;
Json::Reader reader;

reader.parse(data, _root);
```

but none of them work - the first method returns an empty array, the second one results a _root variable, containing the whole json, but I can't make it into an array and create a separate dictionary object for each of the array's elements ( which is what I'm trying to do ).

Comment: you can use rapidjson

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonCPP you mentioned above but with CCFileUtils class

```
unsigned long filesize = 0;
std::string content;
std::string fullPath = "path relative to your androidmanifest.xml/index.json"

unsigned char* fileData = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData(fullPath.c_str(), "r", &filesize);
content.append((char*)fileData);
delete[] fileData;

Json::Value jsonresult;
Json::Reader reader;
bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse( content, jsonresult );
if ( !parsingSuccessful )
{
// report to the user the failure
return false;
}
```